# International calling and data connectivity

Tags: international-travel, recommendations, communication, internet

What are cheap and efficient calling mechanisms when traveling internationally. Also what is a good netbook/internet service that is cheap and available internationally?

Specifically, I am looking for efficient means (could be a calling card or an international SIM from a particular provider or any other mechanism) to call USA and India from Europe. I am looking for responses from those of us who have had personal experience using these services.

Answer (score 5):

This solution may be a basic one, but I've done a fair amount of international travelling and I just bring my unlocked Android Smartphone with me.  Whenever I find an internet wifi hotspot at my hotel or at a cafe, I just Skype my friends and family.  It's free Skype to Skype or you can pay for a subscription (dirt cheap.  I think it's maybe ~$3/month for unlimited calls to landlines and mobile phones).

This is not ideal if you need to call them while you're on the road, in a bus, or in the jungle but I've never had the need to urgently call anyone internationally.